# Can I multiply options in matrix.include[] with the env option?

Tags: travis-ci

Given a fairly heterogenous matrix that looks like this:

```
matrix:
  include:
  - os: linux
    compiler: gcc
    env: PLATFORM=android ARCH=arm64-v8a
  - os: linux
    compiler: gcc
    env: PLATFORM=linux ARCH=aarch64
  - os: osx
    compiler: clang
    env: PLATFORM=darwin ARCH=x86_64 TEST=unit
  - os: osx
    compiler: clang
    env: PLATFORM=ios ARCH=arm64
```

This would result in four builds. I'd like to multiply it by two with an additional environment variable `TYPE=Debug/Release`. What's the best way to achieve this effect? Consider that I've only shown four configurations but the real number of configurations is 15. I'm hoping I won't have to duplicate everything twice.

I've tried the following but it merely adds two more builds, it doesn't combine with the matrix:

```
env:
    matrix:
        - TYPE=Debug
        - TYE=Release
```

Same with this:

```
env:
    - TYPE=Debug
    - TYE=Release
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you cannot.

There is no matrix expansion that you might expect on the top level does not happen in `matrix.include`.

The `env` key forms just one axis of the build matrix, and it is not possible to use different `env` values to construct a build matrix.

The only way to achieve what you need is adding four more jobs:

```
matrix:
  include:
  - os: linux
    compiler: gcc
    env: PLATFORM=android ARCH=arm64-v8a TYPE=Debug
  - os: linux
    compiler: gcc
    env: PLATFORM=linux ARCH=aarch64 TYPE=Debug
  - os: osx
    compiler: clang
    env: PLATFORM=darwin ARCH=x86_64 TEST=unit TYPE=Debug
  - os: osx
    compiler: clang
    env: PLATFORM=ios ARCH=arm64 TYPE=Debug
  - os: linux
    compiler: gcc
    env: PLATFORM=android ARCH=arm64-v8a TYPE=Release
  - os: linux
    compiler: gcc
    env: PLATFORM=linux ARCH=aarch64 TYPE=Release
  - os: osx
    compiler: clang
    env: PLATFORM=darwin ARCH=x86_64 TEST=unit TYPE=Release
  - os: osx
    compiler: clang
    env: PLATFORM=ios ARCH=arm64 TYPE=Release
```

(Incidentally, where are you getting the number 15?)

Comment: What I meant was that in my `.travis.yml` file, there literally is 15 configurations and that I'd like to avoid doubling them just for the sake of `Debug/Release` dimensions. I only showed 4 to demonstrate that each was unique enough that I think I can't "factor out" anything out of them and that, AFAIK, I'm kinda stuck spelling them out. Therefore, I was hoping I could avoid spelling them out further and end up with 30 configurations. Seems like I have no choice, though. Thanks.

Comment: But here's a related question: could I not do something like `env: PLATFORM=... ARCH=... TYPES=Debug,Release` and in my `script:` loop over the values in `TYPES`?

Comment: The problem is no different whether you have 2 or 15 values you want for a particular environment variable. There is no matrix expansion, and you'll have to write them all out. The tools like what @renemilk showed may ease your pain, but it is still present.

Comment: Use of `,` in the right hand side is dubious because it is a valid character.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a small python script with a (jinja) template included to generate my travis config.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

tpl = '''
script:
    - some_stuff.bash

matrix:
  include:
{%- for letter, number in vars %}
    - env: TESTS={{number}} CONFIG={{letter}}
{%- endfor %}

'''

import os
import jinja2
from itertools import product

tpl = jinja2.Template(tpl)
ymlfn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.travis.yml')
with open(ymlfn, 'wt') as yml:
    yml.write(tpl.render(vars=product(['a', 'b'], range(5))))
```

[extend example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dune-community/dune-gdt/master/.travis.yml.py)